# EF4 Code First tying to Membership Role's User

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Playing with code first, and want to keep track of a user's state related to certain items.  To contrive an example, let's say I've got

```
public class Currency
{ 
    public decimal Value {get;set;}
    public string OldDude {get;set;}
}

public class UsersCurrencyAmount
{
    virtual public Currency {get;set;} //type of currency in my man-purse
    int quantity {get;set;}
    //how do I refer to MembershipUser here?
}
```

Do I use MembershipUser directly through some magic, or do I make something like a

```
public class User
{
    int UserId {get;}
    string UserName {get;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create a dependency from your domain model to the .NET Membership. You should have a `User` class in your domain. At a higher level in your application you could use the membership model (most likely through an abstraction) to implement authorization needs.

Comment: While generically I agree with you, it seems to me that the membership role exists to provide a baseline of functionality and wouldn't be a flaw to depend directly upon it.  The main reason for doing this is referential integrity in the database.  That said, your point did make (new to asp.net) me google "membership role sucks", which gave enough hits to make me think that making an abstraction layer probably wouldn't be a bad thing.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of some help.